# diaplays same data in react js, if condition not working or working but map function takes all value without sorting

Tags: reactjs, map-function

hello i am facing problem with duplicate values showing in calender insted of sorted value according to conditions can any one resolve this issue

```
async componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/timesheet/count", { responseType: "json" })
      .then((response) => {
        const countData = response.data.result;
        const rejectData = response.data.result;
        console.log(countData);
        countData.map((item, index) => {
          if (item.approved > 0) {
            item.title = `approved: ${item.approved}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("app");
          } else if (item.rejected > 0) {
            item.title = `rejected: ${item.rejected}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("rej"); 
          } else if (item.submitted > 0) {
            item.title = `submitted: ${item.submitted}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("sub");
          } else {
            item.title = `Not Submitted: ${item.saved}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("not");
          }
          console.log("1st item",item);
          return item;
        });

        rejectData.map((secitem, index) => {
          if(secitem.date == '10-March-2021'){
            secitem.title = `rejected: ${secitem.rejected}`;
            secitem.start = new Date(secitem.date);
            secitem.end = new Date(secitem.date);
            console.log("2nd secitem",secitem);
          }
          else{
            console.log('empty strusidohjaskj jas');
          }
         
        //  return item;

        });
        const tdate = [...countData];
        const rejdate = [...rejectData];

        this.setState({
          countData: {
            data: [...tdate],
          },
          rejectData: {
            data: [...rejdate],
          },
        });
      })
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebYpE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your `countData` and `rejectData` contain the same data, so if you add both on your callendar you will get duplicates.

This happens because you start with

```
const countData = response.data.result;
const rejectData = response.data.result;
```

Perhaps you should change it to

```js
const countData = response.data.result.filter(({ rejected }) => !rejected);
const rejectData = response.data.result.filter(({ rejected }) => rejected);
```

Comment: i changed certain things but things doesnt gets sorted

Comment: @MukeshSingh you are not sorting anything in your code. Please update your question and add sample data `response.data.result` and how you use `state.countData` and `state.rejectData`. And post how you expect it to show

Comment: thanks for your response I edited my question pls have a look  .. :)  @Gabriele Petrioli

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and result is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeYlh.jpg

```
const countData = response.data.result.filter(({ approved }) => approved);
        const rejectData = response.data.result.filter(({ rejected }) => rejected);
        console.log(countData);
        countData.map((item, index) => {
          if (item.approved > 0) {
            item.title = `approved: ${item.approved}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("app");
          } else if (item.rejected > 0) {
            item.title = `rejected: ${item.rejected}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("rej"); 
          } else if (item.submitted > 0) {
            item.title = `submitted: ${item.submitted}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("sub");
          } else {
            item.title = `Not Submitted: ${item.saved}`;
            item.start = new Date(item.date);
            item.end = new Date(item.date);
            console.log("not");
          }
          console.log("1st item",item);
          return item;
        });

        rejectData.map((secitem, index) => {
          if(secitem.rejected > 0){
            secitem.title = `rejected: ${secitem.rejected}`;
            secitem.start = new Date(secitem.date);
            secitem.end = new Date(secitem.date);
            console.log("2nd secitem",secitem);
          }
          else{
            console.log('empty strusidohjaskj jas');
          }
         
        //  return item;

        });
        const tdate = [...countData];
        const rejdate = [...rejectData];

        this.setState({
          countData: {
            data: [...tdate],
          },
          rejectData: {
            data: [...rejdate],
          },
        });
      })
```

response.data.result

```
{
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
approved: 2
date: "12-March-2021"
end: Fri Mar 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
id: 3
not_submitted: 4
rejected: 2
start: Fri Mar 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
submitted: 0
title: "rejected: 2"
__proto__: Object
1:
approved: 0
date: "07-March-2021"
id: 1
not_submitted: 4
rejected: 0
submitted: 0
__proto__: Object
2:
approved: 2
date: "10-March-2021"
end: Wed Mar 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
id: 2
not_submitted: 4
rejected: 2
start: Wed Mar 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
submitted: 0
title: "rejected: 2"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
}
```

I used this data in calender events

```
events={[
              ...this.state.countData.data,
              ...this.state.rejectData.data,
]}
```

expected outcome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX17d.jpg